# Is there anything in the latest version of Typescript that would simplify function chaining?

Tags: javascript, typescript

My code is looking like this:

```
return tes.setStatus(UserTestStatus.Paused)
  .then(() => {
     return tes.getTests(exs.exam.examId)
        .then(() => {  
           tes.setCurrent($stateParams.testId);
        });
  });
```

I have this kind of thing many times in my code but I am not sure if I could simplify it in any way. Note that setStatus and getTests both return promises. setCurrent does not return a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will target ES6 and use Typescript 1.7 or later you can use await/async:

```
await tes.setStatus(UserTestStatus.Paused);
await tes.getTests(exs.exam.examId);
return tes.setCurrent($stateParams.testId);
```

And your functions setStatus and getStatus marked with async like this:

```
public async setStatus(status: any): Promise<any>
```

Comment: I looked here https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ but cannot see anything about supporting await.  Do you know if the latest browsers support this yet?

Comment: yes everything on latest googles V8 engine supports it. This includes Chrome and node.js

Comment: async/await is not an ES6 feature. When you use it in TypeScript the emitted code uses generators & promises. The generators requirement is why you have to target ES6. Experimental browser support for async functions is on the [esnext page](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/).